# Using resample vs. aggregate & extend in R to have rasters of matching resolution and extent

Tags: raster, r, extents, resolution

I have two rasters of different resolution and extent:

```
> res(Elevation)
[1] 0.002083333 0.002083333

> res(Ann_precip)
[1] 0.008333333 0.008333333 

> extent(Elevation)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -15.07722 
xmax        : -7.641806 
ymin        : 7.193611 
ymax        : 12.67694 

> extent(Ann_precip)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -15.075 
xmax        : -7.641667 
ymin        : 7.191667 
ymax        : 12.675
```

**My question is**, in order for these two rasters to have matching resolutions and extents, is it better to:

**A)** use the `raster::aggregate` function

```
> 0.008333333/0.002083333
[1] 4

Elevation_res<-aggregate(Elevation, fact=4, fun=mean)
```

and the `raster::extend` function

```
Elevation_res<-extend(Elevation_res, Ann_precip, values=NA)
```

(although here I still get different but very similar extents and resolutions):

```
> res(Elevation_res)
[1] 0.008333333 0.008333333

> res(Ann_precip)
[1] 0.008333333 0.008333333

> res(Elevation_res)==res(Ann_precip)
[1] FALSE FALSE

> extent(Elevation_res)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -15.07722 
xmax        : -7.635556 
ymin        : 7.193611 
ymax        : 12.67694 

> extent(Ann_precip)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -15.075 
xmax        : -7.641667 
ymin        : 7.191667 
ymax        : 12.675
```

**or**

**b)** use the `raster::resample` function

```
Elevation_res<-resample(Elevation, Ann_precip, method="bilinear")

> res(Elevation_res)==res(Ann_precip)
[1] TRUE TRUE

> extent(Elevation_res)==extent(Ann_precip)
[1] TRUE
```

I'm asking this because I've read in [Wegmann et al (2016)](http://book.ecosens.org/) (p110) (if I understand correctly) that resampling greatly affects pixel values, and that `aggregate()`,`extend()` and `crop()` should be used instead. 
Since differences in resolution and extent are quite small in my case, can I assume that bias created by resampling would be minimal here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check [`resample` function of `raster` package](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/resample.R). When `resample` is used with `'bilinear` method, the output is the same one than `aggregate`:

```r
if (!skipaggregate) {
    rres <- res(y) / res(x)
    resdif <- max(rres)
    if (resdif > 2) {
        ag <- pmax(1, floor(rres-1))
        if (max(ag) > 1) {
            if (method == 'bilinear') {
                x <- aggregate(x, ag, 'mean')
            } else {  
                x <- aggregate(x, ag, modal)
            }
        }
    }
```

With an example:

```r
library(raster)

r <- raster(nrow=4,ncol=8)

r2 <- raster(nrow=2,ncol=4)

r <- setValues(r,values = 1:32)

r_agg <- aggregate(r,fact=2,fun=mean)

r_resam <- resample(r,r2,method='bilinear')

values(r_resam) == values(r_agg)
## [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

values(r_resam)
## [1]  5.5  7.5  9.5 11.5 21.5 23.5 25.5 27.5
```

But if you use `'ngb'` as method, the result is different (method depends of your data, if is categorical you **must** use `'ngb'`):

```r
r_resam2 <- resample(r,r2,method='ngb')

values(r_resam2)
## [1] 10 12 14 16 26 28 30 32
```

And extend doesn't change resolution, only extent:

```r
r
## class       : RasterLayer 
## dimensions  : 4, 8, 32  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
## resolution  : 45, 45  (x, y)
## extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

r_ext <- extend(r,r2,values=NA)

r_ext
## class       : RasterLayer 
## dimensions  : 4, 8, 32  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
## resolution  : 45, 45  (x, y)
## extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

And `crop()` as `extend()`, will no change resolution.

Comment: @MarieL sorry, is extent (I misspelled the word)

Comment: Is the `bilinear` option equivalent to `mean` as the function for `aggregate` and `ngb` option equivalent to `modal`? I am referring to cases where the target is coarser resolution (larger pixel size) than the input that needs to be transformed.

Comment: @user3386170 yes, check these lines: https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/4d218a7565d3994682557b8ae4d5b52bc2f54241/R/resample.R#L42