# Can I resample a raster in R using "max" as function?

Tags: raster, r, resampling, aggregate, max

With a raster and a reference raster, I'd like to do something like this:

```
# resample raster to ref_raster to match resolution/origin using max as aggregate
raster = resample(raster, ref_raster, 'max')
```

How can I optimally achieve this?

The `raster::resample` function offers two different options to resample: `ngb` (Nearest Neighbor) and `bilinear` (basically a mean, as I understand). From [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255150/using-resample-vs-aggregate-extend-in-r-to-have-rasters-of-matching-resolutio) I gathered that resample basically calls `aggregate`, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/4d218a7565d3994682557b8ae4d5b52bc2f54241/R/resample.R#L42):

```
if (method == 'bilinear') {
    x <- aggregate(x, ag, 'mean')
} else {  
    x <- aggregate(x, ag, modal)
}
```

I haven't found an option to use other functions for [`resampling`](https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/man/resample.html) (functions like `aggregate` would allow, e.g. *max*, *min* or any function transforming multiple values to one and accepting a na.rm argument).

I also haven't found an option to make [`aggregate`](https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/man/aggregate.html) match the origin, as `resample` would do. Also if using aggregate, I'll first have to calculate the factor myself, which isn't a huge issue, but doesn't make for short code.

Is the "right" approach then to first `aggregate` (to match the resolution) and then `resample` (to match the origin)? Or is there an easier (and less computationally expensive) option?

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom function using resample code and changing the function line?

Comment: no - to be honest, not understanding parts of the code of the resample function made me reluctant to adopt it. It uses several functions/constructs that I'm not familiar with - starting with the signature `setMethod('resample', signature(x='Raster', y='Raster'), 
function(x, y, method="bilinear", filename="", ...)`, what does setMethod do here? You think simply changing `x <- aggregate(x, ag, 'mean')` to `x <- aggregate(x, ag, 'max')` in [line 43](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/4d218a7565d3994682557b8ae4d5b52bc2f54241/R/resample.R#L43) is sufficient? (call with 'bilinear' for max)

Comment: You can use the `terra` package to resample a raster using the `max` as a function. This might help you (https://rdrr.io/github/rspatial/terra/man/resample.html)

Comment: perfect, that's what I'm looking for. If you make it into an answer, I'll accept it!